# Same iptables rules for two different iptables versions

Tags: iptables, routing, netfilter

I use a set of iptables rules that makes use of the mangle table, which contains the rows below, on two different versions of iptables **v1.3.8**, and **v1.4.7**.

Iptables v1.3.8 runs on Fedora release 8 kernel 2.6.23.1-42.fc8
Iptables v1.4.7 runs on Scientific Linux (a RHEL clone) 6.10 kernel 2.6.32-573.1

Both PCs are configured in the same way, but in the **older** version of iptables **v1.3.8** the configuration is working, it is not in **v1.4.7**

The rules are :

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -s 10.200.0.0/16 ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -s 192.168.0.0/16 ! -d 192.168.0.0/16 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --save-mark
iptables -t mangle -I OUTPUT -m connmark ! --mark 0 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -s 172.16.62.100 -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -s 172.16.61.2   -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -s 172.16.61.3   -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -s 172.16.61.4   -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -s 172.16.61.5   -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -s 172.16.61.6   -j MARK --set-mark 2
iptables -A OUTPUT -t mangle -s 172.16.61.7   -j MARK --set-mark 2
```

The **/etc/sysconfig/iptables** file present in the version **v1.3.8** contains the following lines :

```
*mangle
-A PREROUTING -s 10.200.0.0/255.255.0.0 -d ! 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1 
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 -d ! 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 
-A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0x0 -j CONNMARK --save-mark 
-A OUTPUT -m connmark ! --mark 0x0 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.62.100 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.2 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.3 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.4 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.5 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.6 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.7 -j MARK --set-mark 0x2 
COMMIT
```

The **/etc/sysconfig/iptables** file present in the version **v1.4.7** contains the following lines :

```
*mangle
-A PREROUTING -s 10.200.0.0/255.255.0.0 ! -d 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff 
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 ! -d 192.168.0.0/255.255.0.0 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff 
-A PREROUTING -m mark ! --mark 0x0 -j CONNMARK --save-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff 
-A OUTPUT -m connmark ! --mark 0x0 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.62.100 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x1/0xffffffff 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.2 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.3 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.4 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.5 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.6 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff 
-A OUTPUT -s 172.16.61.7 -j MARK --set-xmark 0x2/0xffffffff 
COMMIT
```

In the new version the **set-marks** have become **set-xmark** and **nfmask** and **ctmask** are also present.

Why don't the same rules work in the new version ?

**Update :**

The problem was not on the iptables but on **/etc/sysctl.conf** :

I have set the following parameters and now it works :

```
net.ipv4.conf.default.log_martians = 1
net.ipv4.conf.all.log_martians = 1

net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main change between your two systems isn't *iptables* but the kernel. The older kernel is from 2007.

One notable change that affects routing (which isn't provided by OP in this question but is in [OP's other question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/664230/mark-a-packets-with-iptables-in-order-to-make-a-source-ip-routing)) when used with marks is [`src_valid_mark`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=28f6aeea3f12d37bd258b2c0d5ba891bff4ec479):

> net: restore ip source validation
>
> when using policy routing and the skb mark: there are cases where a
> **back path validation** requires us to use a different routing table for
> src ip validation than the one used for mapping ingress dst ip. One
> such a case is transparent proxying where we pretend to be the
> destination system and therefore the local table is used for incoming
> packets but possibly a main table would be used on outbound. **Make the
> default behavior to allow the above** and if users need to **turn on the
> symmetry via sysctl `src_valid_mark`**

Before this patch (Fedora 8) the behavior with [Strict Reverse Path Forwarding](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3704#section-2.2) (handled by [`rp_filter`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.12#n1427)): assuming symmetric routing, is different than after (SL 6): assuming asymmetric routing for some very special setups where replies are sent one way or an other through a different route.

This ~ 11 years old patch has only been [documented](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/Documentation/networking/ip-sysctl.rst?h=v5.12#n1448) along kernel 5.12 [this year in 2021](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=8cf5d8cc3eae2a6324ff81aa5f2f6c2f52bc5cd0):

> src_valid_mark - BOOLEAN
>
> - 0 - **The fwmark of the packet is not included in reverse path   route lookup**.  This allows for asymmetric routing configurations   utilizing
>   the fwmark in only one direction, e.g., transparent   proxying.
> - **1 - The fwmark of the packet is included in reverse path route   lookup**.  This permits rp_filter to function when the fwmark is   used
>   for routing traffic in both directions.
>
> This setting also affects the utilization of fmwark when performing
> source address selection for ICMP replies, or determining addresses
> stored for the `IPOPT_TS_TSANDADDR` and `IPOPT_RR` IP options.
>
> The max value from `conf/{all,interface}/src_valid_mark` is used.
>
> **Default value is 0**.

So what has to be done to have a symmetrical routing working with marks while keeping Strict Reverse Path Forwarding settings (`rp_filter=1`) is:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
```

or add the equivalent in `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark = 1
```

since the highest value among *all* and any interface value is taken.